# how to set Tag description in Sanic-openapi?

Tags: swagger, sanic, sanic-openapi

I have a Python Sanic server, and now adding the Swagger config to the endpoints. I use Sanic OpenAPI 21.6.0

I can add tag to my endpoints to group them, but can't find how to add tag description. the doc.tag() only accept one parameter and will put it as tag name.

```
@api.get('inlens/admin/lookup')
@doc.tag('Admin')
async def get_job_status(request, user):
```

What I want is like this:
[image: tag description]

Answer (score 0):

Use `summary` to add tag description:

```py
@api.get('inlens/admin/lookup')
@doc.tag('Admin')
@doc.summary('This is admin description')
def get_job_status(request):
    ...
```

[image]